# How many combinations is possible this two particular series

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinations

thanks in advance answering this question.

Suppose i have two series, 
with series 1
$ [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15] $ 
and series $ 2 ,  
[x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x] $ with length=$ 14 $

How can i calculate the amount of possible combinations, when i have to use both series 1 and 2, with the restriction that series 2 must be shorter than series 1.
(For example $ 1,2,6,8,x,x,x $ is allowed, but $ 10,11,15,x,x,x $ is not allowed)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to count all the possible answers regardless of the order of the 'non x' elements of your series, just replace the first series with $(a,a,a,a...a)$.

This simplifies the question to 'How many series can i make with more a's than x's).
When you have computed this number try to calculate for each correct series how many permutations you can find on this series.
Hope this helps.